# How to project/imprint a texture using a mesh as its source

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-painting, texture-baking

I have been trying for days now to make a texture from a mesh pattern (Image B).

The ideal result would be to end with a texture (using the UVs from the **Mesh A**) with the pattern imprinted/baked/projected on to it from **Mesh B**

**A - Mesh to texture:**
[image: Mesh to texture]

**B - Mesh pattern to use as texturing template**
[image: Mesh to use as texturing template]

**C - Desired result, Mesh A with Mesh B as texture**
[image: Desired result]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bake this. Give the texture mesh an emission material. Select the object, then the target object (SHIFT). 
[image]

1. In an image editor create a new texture (square, left)
2. Add an image texture node to the material of the target object,
   select your new texture. It does not have to be connected to
   anything, but make sure it's active (clicked on)
3. In the render settings tab, copy my settings.
4. Press Bake.

Comment: Thank you! This took me 90% of the way there, after following your steps I ended up with some baking problems because my pattern wrapped around the mesh, I ended up using the "cage" option in order to correctly bake the texture.